# Is there Any Windows Terminal Service like for Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-services, remote-desktop

We have some codebar scanners based on Windows CE that run remote applications located on some servers via Windows Terminal Service.

Given that we are migrating our server applications to UNIX based operating systems, I was wondering is there any reliable RDP based solution that can be considered ?

Thanks,

Comment: This belongs on serverfault, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vnc is the main unix alternative for a graphical session other than that you could run some commands over ssh.

Answer (score 3):

Not RDP, there is X-windows. it's not like terminal services, but it might solve your problem (the app runs on the server, only the graphics on the client).

You run the app on the server, and re-route the display to your device.

Comment: This sounds convincing but one subtle confusion, will it still be portable to use over Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

VNC and NX are the two things that perform the same functionality as RDP.

Answer (score 0):

Linux supports many different ways of remoting applications, since you probably want to detach and re-attach to the session then ssh X11 forwarding is out of the picture, which leaves:

- NX: the advantage here is the speed and the fact that you can get seamless sessions. There are many wrappers around the NX libraries, the most popular ones are: x2go and [winswitch](http://winswitch.org/about/) - don't bother with FreeNX and NeatX which are unmaintained.
- [Xpra](http://xpra.org/): does seamless sessions like NX, not full desktops.
- VNC: TigerVNC, TurboVNC, TightVNC, ... I would go with the one that ships with your distro. Full desktops only, not seamless.
- RDP (there are RDP servers for Linux too although I would not recommend them), the RDP clients are fine, although I could not get seamless sessions to work with them...

I have put up a more detailed comparison [here](http://winswitch.org/documentation/protocols/choose.html) - it also explains what seamless sessions are, etc.